# cannot access variable outside jquery each

Tags: jquery

I have asked once, but I was downvoted. However, I still have the problem.

```
    var var1 = "test";
    $.each(portfolioRisksDb, function (index, riskDb) {
           // cannot get var1 here
   });
```

For some, reason `var1` is undefined inside `$.each`. Is it possible? Have I some misunderstanding? It seems that var1 should be directly accessible.

I am attaching also screenshot, where you can see that Chrome shows undefined when I first time read inside $.each loop.

[image]

This is the answer:

If you don't use var1 in the loop (explicitly) it may be garbage collected, so when you're tracing in debugger it may have been destroyed.

Comment: post complete code inside `$.each`. look for typos

Comment: If you don't use `var1` in the loop (explicitly) it may be garbage collected, so when you're tracing in debugger it may have been destroyed.

Comment: it may be because your code is getting executed async so in the each the var1 had not finished being assigned

Comment: You have to post more code, how are you accessing it inside the loop etc? The way you have presented this, it should work exactly as expected.

Comment: Have you tired to simply `console.log(var1)` in your each function?

Comment: Are you sure `portfolioRisksDb` is something that can be iterated over ?

Comment: What is **portfolioRisksDb**? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WeWV4/